# C# Selfmade ListView Item Collection

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compact-framework

I am making my own `ListView`. The `ListView` (a `UserControl`) currently uses a `BindingList` of `ListViewItems` and displays each item.

I am doing an attempt to make my own `ListView` able to bind any Model-Object I want. This is why I made the `ListViewItem` inherit from the `Object` class. But now I am struggling to make a Collection/List that actually contains `ListViewItem` but where you can Add any `Object` you want.

In short: How do I make a `List` or `Collection` that behaves like the `ListBox` or `ListView` Item Collection?

**An Example:**

```
MyListView myListView = new MyListView();

// Add an Object of type MyObject
myListView.Items.Add(myObject);

// Get the object back. (It is returned as a ListViewItem).
ListViewItem sameObjectAsItem = myListView.Items[0];
// Now I should be able to convert the ListViewItem back to MyObject via cast.
MyObject sameObjectAgain = sameObjectAsItem as MyObject;
```

**What I have done so far:**

I have created a class inheriting from `List<Object>`. But I can't cast `MyObject` to `ListViewItem`. Of course I could do a custom Cast converter, but I think I would have to create a new `ListViewItem` object and therefore would loose the reference.

**Why am I doing this:**

I am doing this on a Compact Framework .NET 3.5 project. CompactFramework only provides a basic `ListView` and I am creating a more advanced one. It works perfectly if I would use just `ListViewItems` but I want it to behave like the normal .NET ListView.

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me. Please ask if you need more information.